# Why does the compiler add statements to the switch?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

I have the following reasonably simple switch statement. 
    // earlier
    string fullPath = GetFullPath();
    string type = GetEntityType();

```
switch (type.ToLower()) {
    case "tables":
        tables.Add(fullPath);
        break;
    case "views":
        views.Add(fullPath);
        break;
    case "functions":
        functions.Add(fullPath);
        break;
    case "storedprocs":
        storedprocs.Add(fullPath);
        break;
    case "data":
        data.Add(fullPath);
        break;
    case "layouts":
        layouts.Add(fullPath);
        break;
    case "scripts":
        scripts.Add(fullPath);
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine($"What is this: {type}");
        break;
}
```

When I decompile the resulting binary using Reflector, the `switch(string)` has been changed to ComputeStringHash and then inside each case statement it checks the value via the `if` statement.  Sounds like it's doing double the work.

```
    string s = str2.ToLower();
    switch (<PrivateImplementationDetails>.ComputeStringHash(s))
    {
        case 0x20890fc4:
            if (s == "tables")
            {
                break;
            }
            goto Label_0218;

        case 0x454a414e:
            if (s == "functions")
            {
                goto Label_01DE;
            }
            goto Label_0218;

        case 0x4facf6d1:
            if (s == "views")
            {
                goto Label_01D3;
            }
            goto Label_0218;

        case 0xcdfe2cb3:
            if (s == "storedprocs")
            {
                goto Label_01E9;
            }
            goto Label_0218;

        case 0xd872e2a5:
            if (s == "data")
            {
                goto Label_01F4;
            }
            goto Label_0218;

        case 0x9b4a129b:
            if (s == "scripts")
            {
                goto Label_020C;
            }
            goto Label_0218;

        case 0xba971064:
            if (s == "layouts")
            {
                goto Label_0200;
            }
            goto Label_0218;

        default:
            goto Label_0218;
    }

    first.Add(fullPath);
    continue;
  Label_01D3:
      second.Add(fullPath);
      continue;
  Label_01DE:
      list3.Add(fullPath);
      continue;
  Label_01E9:
      list4.Add(fullPath);
      continue;
  Label_01F4:
      list5.Add(fullPath);
      continue;
  Label_0200:
      list6.Add(fullPath);
      continue;
  Label_020C:
      list7.Add(fullPath);
      continue;
  Label_0218:
    Console.WriteLine("What is this: " + str2);
}
```

Comment: How were you expecting it to be implemented instead, and why do you think your implementation would be faster?

Comment: There's a reason why C, C++ or Java (until Java 7) don't allow switch statements on anything but integers.

Comment: Even string compare in good old C is basically an ASCII code comparison bit by bit.

Comment: @JerryLiang Wouldn't it compile it down to assembly comparing blocks of memory?

Comment: @AngryHacker yeah specifically if you are using memcmp() it does compare blocks of memory, however strcmp() made for string is bit by bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very smart optimization, which lets the `switch` do its job in time that is almost independent of the number of strings in the `case` block of the statement.

This optimization is based on the observation that hash codes of identical strings must be the same. Rather than checking strings for equality one-by-one, the compiler computes a hash of the target string once, and performs a table-based lookup in O(1). This gets the compiler to the desired case, at which point the compiler needs to check that the strings are actually equal.

Note that there would be some rare situations when multiple look-up strings would have the same hash code. In such situations the generated `case` statement would contain multiple `if` to decide among the strings with equal hash codes.

Overall, this behavior mimics the behavior of hash-based dictionaries: hash code determines the `case` (an equivalent of a hash bucket) and the series of `if`s inside determines if there is a match. This results in a better performance, because it lets the compiler skip the unnecessary checks.

Comment: Given the range of hash values, I doubt that it's creating an O(1) lookup table (though I'm not an expert on how switches are implemented, so would be happy to see an authoritative reference).  Even if it just checks the hashes sequentially, though, that would still be more efficient than doing string compares against each value.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger `switch` is always O(1), regardless of the range of the values that you put into it. When the range is wide, code generator puts a hash table behind it.

Comment: I am not seeing the table based lookup.  It's still a switch statement (for integers this time) - so it would have to check each value in the worst case scenario.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - If it's using a hash table to manage the wide range, then it's bucketing the hash codes - which means it is *not* O(1). The marketing material still likes to say that, but mathematically it is not so. (That would be on top of the potential bucketing of strings to has codes that you mentioned.)

Comment: @AngryHacker - All that means, is that when you decompiled it, the process was able to recognize that a case statement was the language construct for which the hash table was created (but not able to work the rest of the way backward to the specific case statement you had typed in).